# How to grab from dati.txt file random links (example 500 links take out 5)

Tags: php

I want to show on first page randomly selected links from a dati.txt file (from about 1000 links 5 randomly selected) from this:

```
<?php

$righe_msg = file("dati.txt");

$numero=0;
foreach($righe_msg as $riga)
{
    $dato = explode("|", trim($riga));

    if (trim($dato[5])=="yes")
    {
        $numero++;
        echo"<tr><td bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>&raquo; <a href='$dato[2]'> $dato[1]</a></td></tr> ";
    }
}

?>
```

About dati.txt
dati.txt is made like this

```
date1.. |title1..|link1...|description1|email1|yes
date2.. |title2..|link2...|description2|email2|yes
date3.. |title3..|link3...|description3|email3|yes
date4.. |title4..|link4...|description4|email4|yes
date5.. |title5..|link5...|description5|email5|yes
date6.. |title6..|link6...|description6|email6|yes
..
```

But how do you get for example (links) out with this code:

```
$links = file("dati.txt");
$numLinks = count($links);
$tmp = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < min(5, $numLinks); $i++)
{
    $randomIndex = rand(0, $numLinks - 1);
    $randomLink = $links[$randomIndex];

    // Avoid duplicates:
    if (in_array($randomLink, $tmp))
    {
        $i--;
        continue;
    }
    $tmp[] = $randomLink;

    echo $randomLink;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is a dati.txt file?

Comment: What is the format of this `datai.txt` file?

Answer (score 1):

Considering 1 link per line:

```
$links = file("dati.txt");
$numLinks = count($links);
$randomIndex = rand(0, $numLinks - 1);
$randomLink = $links[$randomIndex];
echo $randomLink;
```

Getting more links is simply a matter of a loop:

```
$links = file("dati.txt");
$numLinks = count($links);
$tmp = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < min(5, $numLinks); $i++)
{
    $randomIndex = rand(0, $numLinks - 1);
    $randomLink = $links[$randomIndex];

    // Avoid duplicates:
    if (in_array($randomLink, $tmp))
    {
        $i--;
        continue;
    }
    $tmp[] = $randomLink;

    echo $randomLink;
}
```

Comment: Potentially you could end up with 5 of the same links on the page if you were very unlucky.

Comment: That's a characteristic of "random". Surely it's not desired in this example though, so I'm going to fix it - sec.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  $links = file('links.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

  // used this for testing (generated from a file with one link each line (+carriage return)
  //$links = ARRAY('foo 1','foo 2','foo 3','foo 4','foo 5','foo 6','foo 7','foo 8','foo 9','foo 10','foo 11','foo 12');

  $amount = 3;

  shuffle($links);

  $rand_list = array_slice($links, 0, $amount);

  foreach ($rand_list AS $key => $link) {
    print $link.'</br>';
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$righe_msg = file("dati.txt");
$num = 5;
$selected = array();     
while (count($selected)!=$num)
{
   $rand = rand(0,count($righe_msg)-1);
   $selected[$rand] = $righe_msg[$rand];
}
$numero=0;  
foreach ($selected as $sel)
{
   $dato = explode("|", trim($sel));

    if (trim($dato[5])=="yes")
    {
        $numero++;
        echo"<tr><td bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>&raquo; <a href='$dato[2]'> $dato[1]</a></td></tr> ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Potentially you could end up with 5 of the same links on the page if you were very unlucky.

Comment: @Tim ha yes true if not many links. if thats an issue a code upgrade can be provided.

Comment: Yes, sometimes with this modification you get duplicate content. Sincerely Ales